# Finding action on wep api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Hi I am using wep api 2 to create this route. I have

in my WebConfigApi defined

```
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
  //  In Globa.asax
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

My method is decorated as

```
        [Route("api/pO")]
        [AcceptVerbs("Getpo")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<pOver> Getpo()
        {
           ------
        }
```

When I run this using

```
 ../api/pO/Getpo
```

I keep getting error

```
"<Error><Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:60482/api/pO/Getp0'.</Message><MessageDetail>No action was found on the controller 'prO' that matches the request.</MessageDetail></Error>"
```

Please let me know how to decorate it properly to run it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want it to look like this:

```
 [Route("api/pO/Getpo")]
 [HttpGet]
 public IEnumerable<pOver> Getpo()
 {
        ------
 }
```

The AcceptVerbs attribute is meant to do something similar to the HttpGet attribute that you have put on your Action.  you could use AcceptVerbs("GET") in place of the HttpGet attribute.